# Programming of 3 x 7 trick

Tags: c, homework

The puzzle is:

> 1. The deck contains 21 unique numbers
> 2. The numbers should be laid up in rows of 7 (3 rows in total)
> 3. ask the player to memorize a number to start the game
> 4. once the game starts, rearrange the numbers in random in all rows.
> 5. ask the player to select the row the number is in.
> 6. once the player selects, rearrange the numbers for a second time
>
>    1. this time, it is not random but sort the numbers in bundles per row
>    2. stack all the bundles on top of each other, keeping the row selected to be in the centre.
>    3. rearrange it back into rows of 7 such that first number in stack goes to row 1, second to row 2, third to row 3, 4th to row 1 again and so on.
> 7. again ask the player to select the row the number is in.
> 8. repeat step 6
> 9. again ask the player to select the row the number is in.
> 10. point to the middle number of the row selected as the answer.
>
> You can use any programming language to solve this.

I'd like feedback on this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define numRows 3
#define numCols 7
#define TotalNum (numRows*numCols)

void random_rearrange_num(int p[][numCols]) ;
void display(int p[][numCols]) ;
void start();
int row_select(int count);
void stackup(int p[][numCols],int *s,int count);
void back_to_array(int p[][numCols],int *s);


int main()
{  
    //for random numbers
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    //Step 1
    int arr[numRows][numCols] = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11,12,13},{14,15,16,17,18,19,20}};
    int stack[TotalNum] = {0};
    int row = 0;

    //Step 2
    display(arr);

    //Step 3
    start();    

    //step 4
    random_rearrange_num(arr);

    //Step 5 (first time)
    display(arr);
    row = row_select(row);

    //Step 6
    stackup(arr,stack,row);
    back_to_array(arr,stack);

    //Step 7 (second time)
    display(arr);
    row = row_select(row);

    //Step 8:repeat step 6
    stackup(arr,stack,row);
    back_to_array(arr,stack);

    //Step 9 (third time)
    display(arr);
    row = row_select(row);

    //Step 10 and Step 11
    printf("The answer is : %i",arr[row][3]); 

    return 0;
}
void random_rearrange_num(int p[][numCols])
{
  int temp = 0,k= 0,l = 0;
  for(int i = numRows-1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
  {
    for (int j = numCols-1;j>0; j--)
    {
          k = 0 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(2-0+1)+1);
          l= 0 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(6-0+1)+1);
          temp = p[i][j]; 
          p[i][j] = p[k][l];
          p[k][l] = temp;
    }
  }
}

void display(int p[][numCols])
{
       //printf("\n");
       for (int i = 0; i< numRows;i++)
       {
          for ( int j = 0;j< numCols;j++)
          {
            printf("%8i",p[i][j]);
          }
          printf("\n");
       }
}

void start()
{
        printf("\n");
        printf("Please memorize a number(between 0 to 20) and press enter to continue");
        char c=getchar();
        while (c != '\n')
            c=getchar(); 
        printf("\n"); 
}
int row_select(int count)
{
     printf("\n");
     printf("Please select the row the number is in(between 1 to 3):");
     scanf_s("%i",&count);
     return count-1;
}


void stackup(int p[][numCols],int *s,int count)
 {         
    int k = 0,t= 0;  
    int middle = (numRows-1)/2;  
    for (int i = 0; i<numRows; i++)
    {        
        t=i;      
        if (i==middle || i==count)  
            i = (i==count)?middle:count;  
        for (int j = 0; j<numCols; j++)    
        {
            s[k++] = p[i][j];
        }
        i=t;    
    } 
} 
void back_to_array(int p[][numCols],int *s)
{
  int k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< numCols;i++)
       {
          for ( int j = 0;j<numRows;j++)
          {
             p[j][i] = s[k++];
          }

       }
}
```

Comment: This is a minor point, but don't use `define` to set constants. You should instead use something like `const int NUM_ROWS = 3;` which provides type safety.

Comment: so when shld you use define? any examples?

Comment: @lakesh You should only use #define for preprocessor uses, like #define DEBUG, though this is often done at a higher level, i.e. in the IDE/preprocessor.

Answer (score 3):

Your `random_rearrange_num` function has a bias.  If you want an equal chance of getting every permutation, implement something like the Fisher-Yates shuffle.  Your implementation is actually a common implementation error.  You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors).

I would implement it as follows: (my C is mighty rusty and I don't have a compiler on hand to verify syntax or correctness)

```
void random_rearrange_num(int p[][numCols])
{
  int r, k, l, temp;
  for (int i = numRows * numCols - 1; i > 1; i--)
  {
    r = rand() % i; //select from only the remaining numbers
    k = r / numRows;
    l = r % numRows;
    temp = p[i][j]; 
    p[i][j] = p[k][l];
    p[k][l] = temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Your indentation and whitespace is inconsistent.  It looks like you're mostly using four-space indentation, and as such, it should be applied everywhere.
- Your function-naming can be improved:

  - `display()` can be renamed to specify what it displays.
  - `start()` can be renamed to reflect what it is actually doing.  It may be performing some initial task, but it's not quite clear from the name alone.
  - The name `back_to_array()` sounds a little strange and the functionality doesn't seem to help clarify its intent.
- The stray `printf("\n");` calls are a little cumbersome.  You can just add the `"\n"` to the very start of the `printf()` calls that follow.  It will still be clear that you're trying to start a newline.
- It doesn't look like `row_select` needs to both modify its parameter and then return a new value.  You could just read into a local variable and then just return that.

  Also, it appears that `scanf_s` is Microsoft-specific thus is non-portable.  The portable version would be `scanf()`.  However, as you have already `stdafx.h` included, it's already clear that this code depends on a Microsoft environment.  For you, this would only be an issue if you'd like to share this code with someone else with a different environment.